# How to know the expectation of squared normal distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Suppose Xi iid normal($\theta, \theta$). The second $\theta$ is variance. I want to know $E[(\Sigma X_i^2)^2]$. Any doable method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: you can just expand the square, and use linearity of expectation and independence to get
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\!\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2\right)^2\right]
&= \mathbb{E}\!\left[\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n X_i^2 X_j^2\right]
= \mathbb{E}\!\left[\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^4\right]+2\mathbb{E}\!\left[\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}X_i^2X_j^2\right]\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}[X_i^4]+2\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\mathbb{E}[X_i^2]\mathbb{E}[X_j^2] \\
&= n\cdot \mathbb{E}[X_1^4] + \binom{n}{2}\cdot \mathbb{E}[X_1^2]^2
\end{align}$$
so all you need is to compute $\mathbb{E}[X_1^4]$ and $\mathbb{E}[X_1^2]$ for a normal distribution, which is well known.